# Highlight html table cell onclick and copy value with CTRL + C

Tags: javascript, html, html-table, cell

I found a nice script to highlight html table rows and it works fine :

http://nerds-central.blogspot.ca/2006/12/selectable-table-rows-with-html-and.html

I changed the onclick event for onmouseover and I added a few lines to select a cell onclick. So, I'm able to select it, to check which one is selected and get the value, but I want to copy the cell value on pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> without having to select the content (like in Microsoft Excel).

Just <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> should be ok, but if you also have a clue to do the trick with the right-click dropdown menu, that would be awesome!

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/400212/how-to-copy-to-the-clipboard-in-javascript
A full cross browser compatible solution would require Flash, as  most browsers to readily allow access to a computer's clipboard.

Comment: can you provide a fiddle so we have something to work with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a snippet which automatically selects a cell just before copy, though it works with <kbd>CTRL+C</kbd> only.

```
window.onload = function () {
    var selected,
        selectCell = function (e) {
            var cell = e.target,
                range, selection;
            if (cell.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'td') {
                while (cell = cell.parentElement) {
                    if (cell.tagName.toLowerCase() === 'td') {
                        break;
                    }               
                }
            }
            if (!cell || cell.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'td') {
                return;
            }
            if (selected) {
                selected.style.backgroundColor = '';            
            }
            cell.style.backgroundColor = '#ff0';
            selected = cell;
        },
        beforeCopyCell = function (e) {
            var range, selection;
            if (!selected || !e.ctrlKey || e.which !== 67) {
                return;
            }
            selected.focus();
            selection = window.getSelection();
            selection.removeAllRanges();
            range = document.createRange();
            range.selectNode(selected);             
            selection.addRange(range);
        },
        afterCopyCell = function (e) {
            if (!selected || !e.ctrlKey || e.which !== 67) {
                return;
            }
            selection = window.getSelection();
            selection.removeAllRanges();
        },
        table = document.getElementById('table');
    table.addEventListener('click', selectCell);
    table.addEventListener('keydown', beforeCopyCell);
    document.body.addEventListener('keyup', afterCopyCell);
};
```

The code seems to work well in FF25, Chrome31 and IE11, but it's not working in IE<9.

[A live demo at jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/54ERx/). (The fiddle demonstrates an alternative code, which doesn't work well with IE.)

[Another demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xtjxL/), which somehow implements also copying the cell via contextmenu. This works in FF26, Chrome31 and IE11 only, though if omitting/rebuilding the class toggling of the selected cell, the code is supposed to be IE9+ combatible.

Comment: Nice! This is so nice! Thanks!!

Comment: I found this solution really helpful too: http://forums.devshed.com/javascript-development-115/onclick-to-select-all-text-in-a-cell-825002.html and this one to change the text selection color: http://www.developerdrive.com/2013/10/how-to-change-text-selection-color-with-css/